# Replace values of the left column with pandas if a certain letter appears in right column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, filter

I have a dataset in excel with this table and I want to use pandas.

> ```
>  Date      Hour       SO2     Flag
> 22/05/2023  14:00     0.75      V
> 22/05/2023  15:00     0.79      M
> 22/05/2023  16:00     0.75      V
> 22/05/2023  17:00     0.79      V        
> 22/05/2023  18:00     0.65      Z
> ```

I want to replace the values of a cell in "SO2" with NaN if the letter of the right cell in the column "Flag" is M or Z.

I want the table looks like:

> ```
>  Date      Hour       SO2     Flag
> 22/05/2023  14:00     0.75      V
> 22/05/2023  15:00     NaN       M
> 22/05/2023  16:00     0.75      V
> 22/05/2023  17:00     0.79      V        
> 22/05/2023  18:00     NaN      Z
> ```

And then export to an xlxs.

I could try with *replace*  but I don't know how to modify xls.replace to add an if:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd


xls = pd.read_excel('/content/data.xls', sheet_name='Horario')

data2 = xls.replace('*', '')

data2.to_excel('/content/fil2.xlsx',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mask here:

```py
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd


xls = pd.read_excel('/content/data.xls', sheet_name='Horario')

replace_mask = xls['Flag'].isin(['M','Z'])
xls.loc[replace_mask,'SO2'] = np.nan

data2.to_excel('/content/fil2.xlsx',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The loc accessor is used to locate the rows where the corresponding value in the `Flag` column is either `M` or `Z`, and the values in the `SO2` column of those rows are replaced with **NaN** using the `float('nan')` syntax.

```
# Import file as you did

xls.loc[xls['Flag'].isin(['M', 'Z']), 'SO2'] = float('nan')

# Export file as you did
```